# Angular 2: Pressing the enter key triggers a method and I don't know how to stop it

Tags: angular, events, keypress

I've written a form, bound to an angular 2 component. When I press the enter-key in any text-input it starts a method bound to a (click) event event of a button.

This is the textfield where i press the enter-key:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" [ngModel]="tutorial.name" #name="ngModel" required>
```

This is the button-click-method which gets triggered:

```
<button class="btn btn-success button-right" (click)="addEasy('')">+</button>
```

The button calls the 'addEasy()' method. This method pushes a new empty element to an array. The array is bound to an *ngfor. So whenever I press the enter button inside the first text-input-field i get another empty row inside my *ngFor.

I really have no idea how to solve this problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prevent the form from submitting on enter, add the following in your `<form>` tag:

```
<form (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"
```

Comment: used another workaround but i will try this one later. thanks. :)

Comment: ChristianGehn can you please share your workaround here just like @Faisal did ?

Comment: This was driving me nuts, thank you! I don't understand why Angular does this though. I added another button before the one that was getting called and the new one's click event was now triggered. It by default treats the first defined event on any element as the form's submit method?

Comment: how is this a thing lol. I just found that my form (which has no submit button) had the first button's (click) handler also be triggered whenever i pressed enter on any field. I think this should be raised as a bug on Angular's GitHub to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `type="button"` in the button.  With this you still can use enter to submit your form.